# libvirt: how can I make a domain start when the host starts?

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I would like some of my domains to start automatically when my host starts (I'm using libvirt+KVM on ubuntu).  I guess I could put some "virsh start..." statements in rc.local, but is there a way to configure this within libvirt/virsh?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at the output of "help":

```
virsh # help autostart
  NAME
    autostart - autostart a domain

  SYNOPSIS
    autostart <domain> [--disable]

  DESCRIPTION
    Configure a domain to be automatically started at boot.

  OPTIONS
    [--domain] <string>  domain name, id or uuid
    --disable        disable autostarting
```

This requires that you defined the domain from a file (i.e., that the
domain is persistent rather than transient).

Answer (score 17):

If you get the response:

```
    virsh autostart domainname
    "cannot set autostart for transient domain"
```

then

```
    virsh shutdown domainname
    virsh define xmlfile
    virsh start domainname
    virsh autostart domainname
```

In my experience on Ubuntu 12.04, this only happens if a virsh undefine has been run. Domains created with virsh create usually allow setting the autostart immediately after creation.

Comment: This can also happen if you create a domain using an xml file (`virsh create <somevm>.xml`), without defining it (`virsh define <somevm>.xm`l)

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen this happen when you use "create" instead of "define" for a domain.

For example:

`virsh --connect qemu:///system create mytest-vm-20130715.xml`

`virsh --connect qemu:///system autostart mytest-vm`

`error: Failed to mark domain mytest-vm as autostarted`

`error: Requested operation is not valid: cannot set autostart for transient domain`